# RxJava: Merge multiple singles and complete after some have failed

Tags: rx-java2

I would like to merge two `Single<MyData>` such that if one of them fails but the other one succeeds then the error of the one that failed and the emission from the other one are reported, and then the resulting `Single<MyData>` (or `Observable<MyData>`) completes.

If both `Single<MyData>` fail then the result should also fail and also be marked as failed.

What I would like to have at the end is:

- If both succeed then the emitted values and a producer marked as completed.
- If one succeeds and the other fails, the emitted value, the thrown error and the producer marked as complete.
- If all fail, the errors and the producer marked as failed.

It's like an 'OR' operation

Comment: See [Single.mergeDelayError()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#mergeDelayError-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.SingleSource-).

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, I am using it but the problem is that the stream is not marked as complete

Comment: So do you want the error or not?

Comment: @akarnokd What I would like to have at the end is if both succeed then the emitted values and a producer marked as completed. If one ore more succeed, the emitted values the errors and the producer marked as complete. If all fail, the errors and the producer marked as failed. It's like an 'OR' operation

Comment: Flows either succeed (Single, Maybe), complete (Completable, Observable, Flowable) or fail (all) in RxJava, you can't get two different terminal signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. There is only a single terminal event allowed. The contract for `Single` is `success|error`. If you need to receive a next event as well, you should consider to use `Observable` instead. The contract for `Observable` is `next* complete|error`, but you'll still not get a complete.

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(single1.toObservable(), single2.toObservable())
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `Single.create(SingleOnSubscribe)`. If your return type is `Single<MyData>` only one of the responses can be returned, but you could also modify this to instead return a `Single<List<MyData>>` or some other RxJava structure like `Flowable<MyData>` that supports multiple returns. In this example, the `Single<MyData>` returns whichever call returns last because that was the simplest to implement.

```java
public Single<MyData> getCombinedSingle(List<Single<MyData>> singles) {
    return Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<MyData> {
        private boolean encounteredError = false;
        private MyData myData;

        @Override
        public void subscribe(@NonNull Emitter<MyData> emitter) {
            List<Disposable> disposables = new ArrayList<>();
            Consumer<MyData> myDataConsumer = myData -> {
                this.MyData = myData;
                checkForFinish(emitter, disposables);
            }
            Consumer<Throwable> throwableConsumer = throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                encounteredError = true;
                checkForFinish(emitter, disposables);
            }
            for (Single single: singles) {
                disposables.put(single.subscribe(myDataConsumer, throwableConsumer);
            }
        }

        private void checkForFinish(SingleEmitter<MyData> emitter, List<Disposable> disposables) {
            if (disposables1.stream().allMatch(Disposable::isDisposed)) {
                if (encounteredError) {
                    emitter.onError(new Throwable());
                } else {
                    emitter.onSuccess(myData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be modified to return a Throwable from the original Singles if needed.